# Embedding an OpenType Font File

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Below is my code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham;
  src: url("Gotham-Book.otf") format("opentype");
  }
```

I have tried various iterations of this. Have also tried various pathing routes to see if that was the problem. Not sure what exactly the deal is.

Font on my site defaults to what appears to be Times New Roman.

Comment: Have you tried it with `font-family: "Gotham";` quoting the font family?

Comment: @SuperDJ Yup, also have tried single quotes.

Comment: That is the `@font-face` definition that declares the font-family so you can use it, where are you using it in CSS? like this: `body { font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif; }`

Comment: @zgood Here is where Im using it                                                                               body {
  font-family: "Gotham";
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 160px;
}

Comment: @zgood When I inspect element on my site is states that "Gotham" is being computed as the font-family, but the font being displayed is Times New Roman..

Comment: @KevinSavich If you use Chrome developer tools and goto the Network tab, then select Font as a filter, do you see a failed request for your font file or do you not see a request for it at all?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of info on your project's file structure? What folder / file do these CSS rules live in, and what folder does your font file live in?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css.

> This should work if the font is in the same directory of the html file, otherwise you need to set a proper url.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gotham;
    src: url("Gotham-Book.otf") format("opentype");
}
body{
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: Gotham;
}
```